# Symfony2 - Use different classes in a form

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to add two classes in a form. So I do for the second class:

```
            foreach ($formOwnersDetails as $i => $details) {
                $form = $form->add("member_{$i}_has_voting_denied", 'checkbox', array(
                    'data_class' => 'Pro\ConvocationBundle\Entity\OwnerDetails',
                    'property_path' => "votingDenied",
                    'label' => ' ',
                    'required' => false
                ));
```

but it gives me an error:

```
Neither property "votingDenied" nor method "getVotingDenied()" nor method "isVotingDenied()" exists in class "Pro\ConvocationBundle\Entity\Convocation"
```

Why is it looking for `Pro\ConvocationBundle\Entity\Convocation` when I'm adding `data_class` on the field definition?

Comment: You can not set `data_class` parameter to single forms (checkbox, text, any...). If you set the `data_class`, data must be instance of this class, but you set the bool type.

Comment: @ZhukV - I don't make myself clear with adding two different classes to a form. Even looking at the documentation :( Could you give me simple example to achieve it? I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check it but it should work:
Please check documentation for more information [entity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)

```
  $form = $form->add("member_{$i}_has_voting_denied", 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'Pro\ConvocationBundle\Entity\OwnerDetails',
                'property' => "votingDenied",
                'label' => ' ',
                'required' => false
            ));
```